# Laravel Pagination only shows the first page's content

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing an api to get an object array by returning a paginated object. The problem is that accessing first page of the paginate object works fine but second and next pages just only return the first page contents. I just called the URLs like this:

```
/api/get?page=1
/api/get?page=2
```

Data going in:

```
{   
    "page_id":116,
    "descending":true,
    "rowsPerPage":10,
    "page":1,
    "search":null,
    "sortBy":"name",
    "tag_id":null,
    "start_date":null,
    "end_date":null,
    "from_mobile":true 
}
```

Below is my code:

```
    function get_list(Request $req)
    {
        $orderby = "id";
        $order = "DESC";

        $flowdb = Flow::leftjoin("flow_tags", "flow.id", "=", "flow_tags.flow_id");
        $flowdb->leftjoin("tags", "tags.id", "=", "flow_tags.tag_id");
        $flowdb->leftjoin("flow_stocks", "flow.id", "=", "flow_stocks.flow_id");

        $flowdb->select(DB::Raw("flow.id,flow.name,flow.used_count,flow.payload,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('\"','[',tags.id,',', tags.name,']','\"')) as tags, count(flow_stocks.stock_id) as stock_count"));

        $flowdb->where("flow.active", ">", 0);
        $flowdb->where("flow.page_id", $req->page_id);
        $flowdb->groupBy("flow.id");

        if($req->from_mobile)
        {
            $flowdb->where('flow.from_mobile',true);
        }

        if ($req->sortBy) {
            $orderby = $req->sortBy;
        }

        $order = $req->descending ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
        $flowdb->orderBy($orderby, $order);
        $flowdb->orderBy("flow_tags.id", "ASC");

        if ($req->rowsPerPage && $req->rowsPerPage !== -1) {
            $flows = $flowdb->paginate($req->rowsPerPage);
        } else {
            $flows = $flowdb->paginate(999999999);
        }

        return $flows;
}
```

I also tried laravel manual paginator but the error didn't solve.

```
  public function paginator(Request $request, $object, $perPage)
    {
        $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage()??1;
        $currentItems = array_slice($object, $perPage * ($currentPage - 1), $perPage);
        $paginatedItems = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentItems, count($object), $perPage, $currentPage);
        $paginatedItems->setPath($request->url());
        return $paginatedItems;
    }
```

Comment: because you add `999999999` in the number of rows in paginate

Comment: actually this condition never occurs I always set $req->rowsPerPage = 10 bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find out the solution. The problem is I accidentally put `page = 1`  in the request parameter that laravel paginate used this page value (in this case 1) to render results for all pages. I read some online articles about this and found out that laravel starts rendering from page 1 by default if the user didn't give specific `page` value in the request. So, I didn't really need that `page` parameter in this case.

Comment: I wanted to ask if you figured it out, but gladly you did. I wanted to take another look in the evening (as I was actually at work), but I forgotten all about it. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this method. The parameter `$perPage` is how many results you wish to show per page.

```
/**
 * Paginate the given query.
 *
 * @param  int|null  $perPage
 * @param  array  $columns
 * @param  string  $pageName
 * @param  int|null  $page
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)
{
    $page = $page ?: Paginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

    $perPage = $perPage ?: $this->model->getPerPage();

    $results = ($total = $this->toBase()->getCountForPagination())
                                ? $this->forPage($page, $perPage)->get($columns)
                                : $this->model->newCollection();

    return $this->paginator($results, $total, $perPage, $page, [
        'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
        'pageName' => $pageName,
    ]);
}
```

This means something is wrong with setting up the requirements for this condition:

`$req->rowsPerPage && $req->rowsPerPage !== -1`

Double check your queries by using `dd($query)`

I think it would be easier to retrieve the whole dataset as is, without setting condition `flow.page_id, $req->page_id` I think the culprit is somewhere there, but it's difficult to verify without having the data for it.

Finally have you tried calling to `->get()` before `$req->rowsPerPage && $req->rowsPerPage !== -1`:

```
 $flowdb->get();
```

not sure if it would help. But I've seen instances where it was required. Can't think of any examples though.

Comment: if I change the condition to if($req->rowsPerPage){...} the problem didn't solve as well. page_id is a kind of id and I do needs this filter bro. And I think your code is similar to my manual paginator which works well in my other functions but it didn't solve in this case.

Comment: try before if statement ($req->rowsPerPage)

`$flowdb = $flowdb->get();`

Comment: ```$flowdb->get();``` this returns a list of objects but I need to paginate it. by using ```$req->rowsPerPage = 10```. Problem is always showing first page results for all pages.

Comment: You need to paginate the list of objects, that's how paginate works ;/ So it's either that, or something wrong with your queries.

Comment: I passed the resulting object array to my paginator function bro but the problem didn't solve.

Comment: Are you actually getting in the statement? Have you checked that by using dump and die within your statement? If you're not getting in the statement, you should definitely check if your queries are giving you the expected results.

At the point something is not working out as intended, I just use dd() on every variable in the function until it provides me with a solution.

Comment: Can you provide the dataset that goes in the parameter `Request $req` it would help a lot

Comment: ```{
 "page_id":116,
 "descending":true,
 "rowsPerPage":10,
 "page":1,
 "search":null,
 "sortBy":"name",
 "tag_id":null,
 "start_date":null,
 "end_date":null,
 "from_mobile":true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case any one having the same issue using the `http` client, suppose the url is as bellow:

```php
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8002/api/trips?page=3';
```

just `dd` the  response to see which path was actually requested to the server

```php
dd(Http::get($url)->effectiveUri())
```

It look something like this:

```php
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri {#2021 ▼
  -scheme: "http"
  -userInfo: ""
  -host: "127.0.0.1"
  -port: 8002
  -path: "/api/trips"
  -query: "page=3"
  -fragment: ""
}
```

there you can confirm in the `query` field that the page number is what you intended.